# Network Policy not allowing communication inside namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I'm having trouble setting up a Network Policy that looks fine to me. Here are the 2 pods in the same namespace

```
k get po --show-labels
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
nfs-server-ccb8d5ff6-7rtr4   1/1     Running   0          22h   role=nfs-server
nginx-jpm-549b69bf68-x5hd7   1/1     Running   0          21h   app=nginx-jpm
```

And I'm restricting traffic to the nfs-server pod using the following network policy spec:

```
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: nfs-server
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  # Allow inbound from nginx-jpm on all ports
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: nginx-jpm
  egress:
  # Allow outbound DNS traffic inside the cluster (kube-system namespace is not labelled)
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector: {}
    ports:
    - protocol: "UDP"
      port: 53
```

I exec into the nginx pod and am unable to connect to the nfs-server pod

```
root@nginx-jpm-549b69bf68-x5hd7:/# telnet nfs-server.jenkinsrepo.svc.cluster.local 111
Trying 172.22.117.55...
If I delete the network policy, it works then
root@nginx-jpm-549b69bf68-x5hd7:/# telnet nfs-server.jenkinsrepo.svc.cluster.local 111
Trying 172.22.117.55...
Connected to nfs-server.jenkinsrepo.svc.cluster.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Is there something I've missed in my network policy? There is no other network policy in the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `podSelector` which selects pods with `role: nfs-server` label, the egress rule gets applied to only those pods and hence egress is blocked from nginx pod. You should probably create a separate network policy for egress only to cluster DNS which applies to all pods.

Answer (score 0):

Your egress rule is translated as apply these to rules traffic where namespace is not labelled "AND" port 53 UDP , its "AND" of rules. Even though DNS egress traffic might be working, all other egress traffic from all pods in is still blocked, which might be the reason.

if you try the below, it will allow outgoing traffic if: (destination pod has namespace which is not labelled) OR ((port is 53 UDP) OR (port is 53 TCP))

```
egress:
   - to:
     - namespaceSelector: {}
   - ports:                  # 2nd egress rule
     - port: 53                # allow DNS UDP
       protocol: UDP
     - port: 53                # allow DNS TCP
       protocol: TCP
```

link: https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/tutorials/kubernetes-policy-advanced